# Adding a Potentiometer to control the volume of a sub-woofer

Tags: potentiometer

I am adding a sub woofer into a room with 6 speakers (3 sets).  Each set of speakers is on an individual volume control wired back to a niles speaker hub. The speaker hub will be driven by an AudioSource AD508 8-channel multi-room digital power amplifier.  The speaker amp will get its line level signal from a Sonos Connect. (which I already have, and which does not have an output for a sub woofer.) . The sub-woofer has its own dedicated 300 watt amp which can take a speaker level input from the 8 channel speaker amp.

The AV cabinet is one floor below the room I am describing, so I need to be able to control the volume for the sub-woofer from the Sonos App as well as from the room with a hard wired volume control.(the way i can with the speakers)  I have teenage kids, so i need to be able to turn the volume down manually regardless of what they do intentionally or unintentionally when controlling the music from there mobile apps.

The cable run for the sub-woofer is direct from the AV cabinet to the subwoofer location.  This is done and cannot be modified.

I think I want to put a small potentiometer and knob directly above the sub-woofer sticking out through the gypsum board (drywall) for a very subtle but effective solution.

The sub woofer amp is 300 Watts.

Here are my questions:
Am I correct that a potentiometer can be wired to work as a volume control?
What is the spec for the potentiometer I need, given the 300 watt amp?
Where do I get it?
How do I wire it?

Is there a more elegant solution? (i do not want a wireless solution?)

Bonus Question:
The wire from AV cabinet to Sub-woofer is a 4 conductor wire.  Is there a way to take advantage of the extra wires to create a better solution?

Thanks in advance

Comment: “How do I wire it?” ... that’s the million dollar question. Maybe a drawing would help, but I can’t figure out where you are trying to insert your volume control. You say the cable is already run, and cannot be modified, so it sounds like you’re not planning to insert it there. Are you planning to hack the subwoofer? Either way, it’s not likely to work as you expect.

Comment: Look for 'LPAD', high power potentiometer designed for reducing the power going to speakers, so that guitar amps can still be over-driven without shaking the house.

Answer (score 0):

The problem what you will have is that the Amp is wanting an output impedance of 4-32 ohms (depending on the amp). This can do funny things the amps insides and may distort the sound.
The best location for controlling volume is at the pre-amp stage.

If the 4 conductor wire is carrying the amplified signal, it not a good idea to run the low signal next to them. The amplified signal will disturb the low signal. If each of the 4 wires are shielded then you may get away with it.